# rewrite this line of javascript

Tags: javascript

In https://codepen.io/kurt_cagle/pen/xqoMBG I find a function walkData with the following statement:

```
var buf = Object.keys(data).map((key)=>`<details><summary  id="${key}" ${Object.keys(data[key]).map((subkey)=>{return subkey != 'children'?`data-${subkey}="${data[key][subkey]}"`:' '}).join(' ')}><img class="icon" src="${me.imageBase}${data[key].icon?data[key].icon:data[key].children?'Folder.png':'Item.png'}"> </img>${data[key].label}</summary>
 ${data[key].children?me.walkData(data[key].children):""}</details>`);
```

As an old-school-non-functional-dinosaur, I find that an unholy mess of map and interpolation which
is almost impossible to follow, debug, or modify. The codepen "Format Javascript" button helps, but
not enough. (I would post that here but the formating defeats me)

Can this be reworked to use longhand loops, intermediate variables, and shorter lines
that ideally do just one thing each.

As a side issue, there are four ` in that one line, can anyone explain to me how the js manages to parse that?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it can be. Are you asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Why not start by simple formatting it in a reasonable way? Since you're making HTML whitespace doesn't matter (much) anyway. Then start pulling stuff out into local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have ended up with (some var names may be a bit cringeworthy).

```
const buf = []
for (const key in data) {
    const dk = data[key];
    const s = [];
    for (const subkey in dk) {
        if (subkey != "children") {
            s.push(`data-${subkey}="${dk[subkey]}"`);
        };
    };
    const sj = s.join(" ");
    const icn = dk.icon ? dk.icon : dk.children ? "Folder.png" : "Item.png";
    const src = me.imageBase + icn;
    const children = dk.children ? me.walkData(dk.children) : "";
    const bi = `<details>
                 <summary  id="${key}" ${sj}>
                  <img class="icon" src="${src}"></img>
                  ${dk.label}
                 </summary>
                 ${children}
                </details>`;
    buf.push(bi);
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I left your original code **in-tact**, I just added appropriate new-lines and indentation.

All I added was:

- A target element to render to
- Some fake `data` that I reverse engineered using the function
- A fake `walkData` function that just returns "CHILDREN"...

**Note:** I could actually refine this code a bit and remove the closing tag for the `<img>` element, since those are unnecessary. The `subkey` map function is also a one-liner, so it can actually be converted to a lambda with not braces nor an explicit `return`; just like the `key` mapper outside of it.

### Example

I little bit of formatting goes a long way. Template literals are great, because you do not have to deal with a mess of string concatenation.

```js
const data = {
  'a': { label: 'Directory A', children: [] },
  'b': { label: 'File B', children: null }
}

const me = {
  imageBase: '/',
  walkData: (children) => 'CHILDREN'
}

const buf = Object.keys(data).map((key) => `
  <details>
    <summary
        id="${key}" ${Object.keys(data[key]).map((subkey) => {
          return subkey != 'children'
            ? `data-${subkey}="${data[key][subkey]}"` : ' '
        }).join(' ')}>
      <img class="icon"
          src="${me.imageBase}${data[key].icon
            ? data[key].icon : data[key].children
              ? 'Folder.png' : 'Item.png'}">
      </img>
      ${data[key].label}
    </summary>
    ${data[key].children ? me.walkData(data[key].children) : ""}
  </details>
`)

document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = buf.join('')
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

## Update

Here is another version that has separate function calls and come comments. It is functionally the same as the previous code.

There are no explicit `return` statements, since all the lambdas are all one-liners.

```js
const data = {
  'a': { label: 'Directory A', children: [] },
  'b': { label: 'File B', children: null }
}

const me = {
  imageBase: '/',
  walkData: children => 'CHILDREN'
}

const main = () => {
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = render(data)
}

const render = data =>
  Object.keys(data).map(key =>
    renderDetails(key, data)).join('')

const renderDetails = (key, data) =>
  `<details>
    <summary id="${key}" ${renderDataAttributes(data[key])}>
      <img class="icon" src="${renderImageSource(data[key])}">
      </img>
      ${data[key].label}
    </summary>
    ${data[key].children ? me.walkData(data[key].children) : ""}
  </details>`

const renderDataAttributes = detail =>
  Object.keys(detail)
    .filter(key => key !== 'children')          // Filter-out children
    .map(key => `data-${key}="${detail[key]}"`) // Map to a data attr
    .join(' ')                                  // Join the values

const renderImageSource = detail =>
  me.imageBase + (
    detail.icon          /* If the detail has an icon,   */
      ? detail.icon      /* Use the defined icon         */
      : detail.children  /* Else, does it have children? */
        ? 'Folder.png'   /* If so, it's  directory       */
        : 'Item.png'     /* Else, it's a file            */
  )

main()
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Honestly I don't find that much easier to read, although it's a good starting point for refactoring. I followed roughly the same process, but pulled out most of the internals. Ended up with three external functions, three locals in the map function, and pretty clean HTML. But since I don't answer OT questions (if anything this belongs on code review) I'll just keep it in my editor and write a blog post or sthng ;)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. I take your point about code review.

Answer (score 1):

Here, us this as a starting point:

```
const buf = []
    
for (const key in data) {
        const t = Object.keys(data[key])
            .map(subkey => {
                return subkey != 'children'
                    ? `data-${subkey}="${data[key][subkey]}"`
                    : ' '
            })
            .join(' ')

        const u = `<details><summary id="${key}" ${t}><img class="icon" src="${
            me.imageBase
        }${
            data[key].icon
                ? data[key].icon
                : data[key].children
                ? 'Folder.png'
                : 'Item.png'
        }"> </img>${data[key].label}</summary>
 ${data[key].children ? me.walkData(data[key].children) : ''}</details>`

        buf.push(u)
}
```